# How to get view count from YouTube APIs for android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

How to get view count from YouTube APIs for android : I am unable to find any document related to getViewCount from YouTube APIs for Android. There is information available for java in general but not for android. 
I am stuck please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id={{VIDEO-ID}}&key={{YOUR-KEY}}

And under the JSONObject for statistics is a field called "viewCount"

Documentation to help you: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource

### If using REST API Client

Here is the sample when you add the statistics part:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": etag,
 "pageInfo": {
 "totalResults": integer,
 "resultsPerPage": integer
},
"items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": etag,
   "id": string,
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": unsigned long,
    "likeCount": unsigned long,
    "dislikeCount": unsigned long,
    "favoriteCount": unsigned long,
    "commentCount": unsigned long
   }
  }
]
```

Just grab the JSONObject called "statistics" and then directly access the field "viewCount".

```
JSONArray items = response.getJSONArray("items");
JSONObject statistics = items.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("statistics");
Long views = statistics.getLong("viewCount");
```

EDIT: to show an actual response and proper access

### If using the Youtube API v3 Module

Add the Youtube API v3 dependency to your project in the app build.gradle folder:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev152-1.21.0'
}
```

That is the header, or jar file, in question you need. Then you can instantiate a YouTube object like I showed above:

```
YouTube youtube = new YouTube.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), new HttpRequestInitializer());

YouTube.Videos.List videoRequest = youtube.videos().list("contentDetails");
 videoRequest.setId("SOME-VIDEO-ID");
 videoRequest.setFields("items/contentDetails");
 videoRequest.setKey("YOUR-API-KEY");
 VideoListResponse response = videoRequest.execute(); //blocking call, ensure to perform off ui thread via AsyncTask 
 List<Video> videosList = response.getItems(); 

 if(videosList != null && videosList.size() > 0){
     Video video = videosList.get(0);
     VideoStatistics statistics = video.getStatistics();
     BigInteger viewCount = statistics.getViewCount();
 }
```

Docs: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/youtube/model/Video.html#getStatistics()

Comment: Thank you. I am actually looking for Android YouTube API. I am developing an App, where I need to find out View Count. Please suggest some Android Code.

Comment: I actually have used this in Android using AsyncHttpClient for the GET requests and such. Let me see what I can do for you

Comment: Also, the Youtube Data API is a module you are using or are you requesting your data via REST API calls like I was discussing.. in any case you are consuming the same API

Comment: @ALS code I added to my answer as en edit should help you.

Comment: Thank you Lucas for your generous help. I am new to Android App development, especially new to use Android YouTube API. Could you please suggest the library header files that I need to import? All I want to do is display the thumbnail and view count in my app and play video when clicked on thumbnail. It would be great if you can provide example code  perform the above tasks. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I added more information. Firstly, the code I put up wouldn't work without the key and these fields you work as well. Secondly, I added the gradle file you would need or the header as you requested. Thumbnails is a separate thing so maybe that would help as well. Note, both methods I described would help you accomplish what you are trying to do (either use a REST API client or use the Youtube API itself)

Comment: Thank you :-) **Much Appreciated!**  I will give it a try and update the thread.

Comment: Right on, remember to perform the execute() function off the UI thread (AsyncTask most likely) to avoid crashing the app as well as enabling the INTERNET permission. Also, best practices say to store API key in a properties file as well but you can always do that later on :)

Comment: I am unable to compile: : I have added your suggestion in build.gradle and also imported some of libraries.
`import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;

import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.ResourceId;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.SearchListResponse;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.SearchResult;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.Thumbnail;`

Comment: link the logcat output

Comment: `VideoListDemoActivity.java
Error:(353, 93) error: HttpRequestInitializer is abstract; cannot be instantiated
Error:(353, 27) error: incompatible types
required: YouTube
found:    Builder
Error:(359, 9) error: cannot find symbol class VideoListResponse
Error:(364, 11) error: cannot find symbol class VideoStatistics`

Comment: Please provide me the list of import files

Comment: Got it. Had to download jar files from: [link](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/setup)

Comment: YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar    google-http-client-protobuf-1.20.0.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar    google-http-client-xml-1.20.0.jar
google/       google-oauth-client-1.20.0.jar
google-api-client-1.20.0.jar    google-oauth-client-appengine-1.20.0.jar
google-api-client-android-1.20.0.jar   google-oauth-client-java6-1.20.0.jar
google-api-client-appengine-1.20.0.jar   google-oauth-client-jetty-1.20.0.jar
google-api-client-gson-1.20.0.jar   google-oauth-client-servlet-1.20.0.jar

Comment: google-api-client-jackson2-1.20.0.jar   gson-2.1.jar
google-api-client-java6-1.20.0.jar   guava-jdk5-13.0.jar
google-api-client-protobuf-1.20.0.jar   httpclient-4.0.1.jar
google-api-client-servlet-1.20.0.jar   httpcore-4.0.1.jar
google-api-client-xml-1.20.0.jar   jackson-core-2.1.3.jar
google-api-services-youtube-v3-rev152-1.21.0.jar jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar
google-http-client-1.20.0.jar    jdo2-api-2.3-eb.jar
google-http-client-android-1.20.0.jar   jetty-6.1.26.jar
google-http-client-appengine-1.20.0.jar   jetty-util-6.1.26.jar
google-http-client-gson-1.20.0.jar   jsr305-1.3.9.jar

Comment: google-http-client-jackson-1.20.0.jar   protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar
google-http-client-jackson2-1.20.0.jar   transaction-api-1.1.jar
google-http-client-jdo-1.20.0.jar   xpp3-1.1.4c.jar

Comment: Cool! Yeah the module is needed or the gradle file should resolve the dependency issues. Please accept my answer if this resolve the issue for you, let me know if you need anymore assistance

Comment: Thanks :-) One more error: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: There were two warnings:     1)    In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
        2)  In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages

Comment: Can you please recommend the jar files needed and imports needed for the code you suggested ?  The Min SDK version I am using is 21.